# how filter data where there is just one word

Tags: pyspark

How I can filter data if there is just one word for a very big data efficiently?

data

```
col1
this is summer
hello
car 
no one
```

output

```
col1
hello
car
```

I did following , just wondering if there is a better solution:

```
data.withColumn('one_token',F.size(F.split(F.col('col1'), ' ')==1)
```

Comment: Instead of splitting, just try to find if space is in it.  Splitting requires making copies of the words!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try this: `data.withColumn('location', locate(' ', trim(col('col1')))).show(10, False).filter(' location > 0 ')`

`pyspark.sql.functions.trim(col)`: Trim the spaces from both ends for the specified string column.

```
data = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('this is summer',),
    ('hello',),
    ('car ',),
    ('no one ',),
], ['col1'])


data.withColumn('location', locate(' ', trim(col('col1')))).show(10, False)

+--------------+--------+
|col1          |location|
+--------------+--------+
|this is summer|5       |
|hello         |0       |
|car           |0       |
|no one        |3       |
+--------------+--------+
```

[pyspark.sql.functions.`locate`(substr, str, pos=1)][1]

Locate the position of the first occurrence of substr in a string column, after position pos.